# What does x === '^' mean?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working through this Angular authorization repo https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth and came across the line `if (fromState.url === '^')` and I have no clue what it means.

You can see it in context here https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/blob/a65505880345abf487aa38c56f24fbf8ab8e12a0/client/js/app.js

To be clear, I'm asking what the caret symbol '^' means in this particular context.

Comment: You mean you don't know what `===` does?

Comment: its probably matching the empty route case, ie what happens when someone goes to the root of your site by just typing in www.example.com. Generally this is the home page or index page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: i can't find a carrot in the server code, which you think would emit it...

Comment: are you asking for the difference between "===" and "==" ?

Comment: I wonder if this is related: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#wiki-absolute-routes-

Comment: @Ian thanks! Submit your comment as an answer and I'll mark it correct :)

Comment: @PaulS. are you being serious? I was pretty sure it was about the absolute route that Ian posted

Comment: correct me if im wrong but i think it just checks if the state you came from is your parent. i.e if you have the following nested states: app ("/"), app.admin ("/admin"), if you change the url to /admin once you are in url: "/" than the event 'StateChangeStart' triggered and fromState.url should be "^". The equivilant syntax in Javascript '===' instead of '==' is basically a way to compare without conversion.